# Node Wrangler not working

Tags: node-editor, add-on

I'm having issues using the *node wrangler* add-on. I've selected my model, went to shading, created a new material, and did <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to find my folder with the different images.

I select them then click *Principled Texture Setup* but nothing happens.

How do I get this to work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you selected the *Principal BSDF* node first? If you haven't selected it then Blender usually tells you this in the status bar - *after* you have selected all images. (So you have to select the images again >,<)

Comment: Did you hilight all 4 image files before clicking the Principled Texture Setup button in the file selector?

Comment: Both of the above comments are relevant.  The Principled BSDF in your screenshot is not selected (no outline) and so the tool won't know what to connect the images to.  The file browser doesn't show any of the files being selected.  You need both of these things.